# Did Queen make any new best sellers after Freddie Mercury's death?

Tags: charts, queen

I recently saw 'Bohemian Rhapsody' which shares and explains Queen and Freddie Mercury's rise and collapse. While I was saddened to hear the way he passed, I'm sure he would have given more hits if he had been alive. Anyways, after Freddie Mercury, did the band continue and did they make some new materials, new hits or it was all gone after Freddie Mercury's death ?

Comment: None that I know of, unlike some other groups that released new songs with material that was previously recorded and then mixed in. Beatles "Free as a Bird", Cranberries just put some stuff out I think, as two examples.

Comment: @CrossRoads - ugh, I've always called it 'freezer bird' which is where it should have been left. It might have been OK if George hadn't given it to Jeff Lynn, who turned it into an ELO record instead :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They made the last Queen album [*Made I Heaven*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Made_in_Heaven) in 1995 using Freddie Mercury's last vocals.

Amongst awards, certifications and singles in the top charts, *Made In Heaven* received, in US a [RIAA Gold Album](https://www.riaa.com/gold-platinum/?tab_active=default-award&ar=Queen&ti=Made+in+Heaven#search_section) and in Europe a [IFPI Quintuple Platinum Album](https://web.archive.org/web/20131127160311/http://ifpi.org/content/section_news/plat1997.html).

They even did a Broadway play [*We Will Rock You*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Will_Rock_You_(musical)) using their music and Brian May has helped google make a [doodle](https://www.google.com/doodles/freddie-mercurys-65th-birthday) commemorated to him.

[image: Freddie Mercury's doodle]

After his death, they made one song together without Freddie Mercury [*No-One but You (Only the Good Die Young)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLKyaOLb2Fs) that reached #13 in UK charts. John Deacon also left the band because he felt it wasn't the same anymore.

Comment: In addition, Brain May and Roger Taylor released an album _[The Cosmos Rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cosmos_Rocks)_ in 2007 under the name Queen + Paul Rodgers.